# I would like to move images in a div so the containing div displays them exactly their size

Tags: javascript

```
function mov_left() {
    if (parseInt(document.getElementById('fold').style.left, 10) == 430) {
        clearInterval(animel);
    }
    document.getElementById('fold').style.left = (parseInt(document.getElementById('fold').style.left, 10) - 10) + 'px';
}

animel = setInterval('mov_left()', 100);
```

This is the code I'm trying to use to move a `<div>` containing 2 images so they can display the two images one at a time. However, the image just keeps moving to the left ignoring the `if` statement in the function.

Help please.

Comment: what is the starting number of px for 'fold'?

Answer (score 0):

well I've fiddled with it, not really much change but I know this works:

```
function mov_left() {
    var el = document.getElementById('fold');
    if (parseInt(el.style.left, 10) == 430) {
        clearInterval(animel);
    }
    el.style.left = (parseInt(el.style.left, 10) - 10) + 'px';
}
animel = setInterval(function () {mov_left(); }, 100);
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/42/

Comment: thanks, I've actually figured out that I was supposed to add the negative sign, (-), before the 430... Thanks for ur speedy reply...

Answer (score 0):

if the left css property of element is not set the element.style.left will return an empty string and parseInt will return NAN.

Comment: I had assigned the css style property to 0 in my original code, which I didn't add to the code I presented in the question.